# Change filtered column in VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen a macro here that works well for filtering and copying data into a new tab. However, it doesn't work when I try to change the filtered column (in this case is column F, but I want to change to column B). See below:

```
Function GetWorksheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName)
End Function

Sub filter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "Sheet1"

'change filter column in the following code
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:F" & last)

Sheets(sht).Range("F1:F" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain specifically what doesn't work (unintended behavior, error message, etc.)

Comment: One potential problem is that if you change column F to B you will only have a two column range and using `Field:=6` will not work.  You will have to change to 2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say if you want this to be re-usable for different sheets then one more layer of abstraction would be useful, so you can call the same sub but with different source ranges:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        FilterRangeToNewSheets .Range("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row), 6
    End With

End Sub

'Given a range and a column index in that range, add new sheets, one for each
'   set of unique values in the range
Sub FilterRangeToNewSheets(rngToFilter As Range, filterColumnIndex As Long)
    
    Dim vals As Collection, k, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = rngToFilter.Worksheet.Parent               'parent workbook
    Set vals = Uniques(rngToFilter.Columns(filterColumnIndex).Offset(1, 0)) 'offset to exclude the header
    
    For Each k In vals
        With rngToFilter
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=filterColumnIndex, Criteria1:=k
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            With wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
                .Name = k
                .Paste Destination:=.Range("A1")
            End With
        End With
    Next k
    rngToFilter.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False ' Turn off filter
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

'extract all unique values from a range into a dictionary
Function Uniques(rng As Range) As Collection
    Dim col As New Collection, data, c As Range, v
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next 'ignore any duplicate key error
            col.Add v, v
            On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
        End If
    Next c
    Set Uniques = col
End Function
```

Swapped out your Advanced Filter for a function which will return a Collection containing only unique values.